# React hook returns before it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, moralis

I’ve encountered a problem with a React hook from the "react-moralis" SDK and need some help.

I’ve implemented the useWeb3Contract hook from the package in an exported function, which should return the result (data) of the function call after fetching the data successfully. However, the function seems to be returning before the data gets fetched successfully.

Here is the code of the function:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useWeb3Contract } from "react-moralis"
import { abi as tokenAbi } from "../../constants/ERC20"

export default function useRetrieveTokenSymbol(address) {
    const {
        runContractFunction: fetch,
        data,
        isFetching,
        isLoading,
    } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: tokenAbi,
        contractAddress: address,
        functionName: "symbol",
        params: {},
    })

    const retrieve = async () => {
        await fetch()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       retrieve()
    }, [])

    if (!isFetching && !isLoading && data) return data
}
```

This function then gets called in a separate react component, where it should only return the data from the useWeb3Contract hook, which then can be stored in a variable.
That looks like that:

```js
export default function TokenSymbol({tokenAddress}) {

const tokenSymbol = useRetrieveTokenSymbol(tokenAddress)

return (
<div>{tokenSymbol}</div>
)

}
```

tokenSymbol however always is undefined, because the useRetrieveTokenSymbol function returns before finishing fetching the data and then returns an undefined data constant. The conditional if statement gets completely ignored and I simply cannot figure out why.

Any of you guys know a fix to this? Would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Where does `retrieveAddress` come from? What are you doing with the result?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how async and await work. Indeed, the `await` you use in the retrieve function has no effect, since no code is executed after the await.

Comment: Have you enabled web3? The `useWeb3Contract` hook is dependent on a web3 provider to work. Please check the forum post you made.

Comment: The `isFetching`, `isLoading` and `data` values come from the `useWeb3Contract`, perhaps you should check *that* hook's code to see why the returned `data` value isn't what you expect.

Comment: web3 is enabled. The problem however is, that the function returns or finishes before data is fetched. Is there any way to make the function (useRetrieveTokenSymbol) wait returning before data is fetched (data being anything else than null)?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the values you are tracking in state. That way, when they update, the hook will cause a re-render:

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState(data);

useEffect(() => {
  setMyData(data);
}, [data]);

return myData;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the function still returns undefined and does not re render. Same result

Comment: Are you actually getting a result back from your API call? What does the network tab show?